# Oracle: Replacing package body stuck

Tags: oracle, session, timeout

I have two schemas in my oracle database: XXX_MONITORING and XXX_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION. I had a script running on MONITORING_CONFIGURATION which is run with SQLPlus to update the database.

I split this script into two parts where the new part (lets call it part one) is run on XXX_MONITORING, and contains only a XXX_MONITORING.MONITORING package body replace. I also changed the package body so that it has three new functions.

Now the part one tries to be run, but it gets stuck and I get a timeout message.

I tried to trouble shoot this on the assumption that the problem is database locks, and run the following script:

```
SELECT s.sid,
   s.SERIAL#,
   s.STATUS,
   s.STATE,
   l.lock_type,
   l.mode_held,
   l.mode_requested,
   l.lock_id1
FROM   dba_lock_internal l,
   v$session s
WHERE s.sid = l.session_id
AND UPPER(l.lock_id1) LIKE '%MONITORING%'
AND l.lock_type = 'Body Definition Lock';
```

After killing some sessions `alter system kill session '51,20351';`, as a result I get:

```
397 33707   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING_WEB_SELF_IVR
51  20351   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING_WEB_SELF_IVR
397 33707   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.MONITORING
51  20351   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.MONITORING
397 33707   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING
51  20351   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING
199 1171    ACTIVE  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING
```

The sessions are still there after waiting half an hour.

How can I recover from this situation? Should I have updated the package header before adding new functions to the MONITORING package body?

The application using the database is shut down. There might be scheduled database jobs running.

When I run the script one in SQLPLus, the output of the sessions-script changes:

```
397 33707   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING_WEB_SELF_IVR
51  20351   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING_WEB_SELF_IVR
397 33707   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.MONITORING
51  20351   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.MONITORING
447 5465    ACTIVE  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Exclusive   None    XXX_MONITORING.MONITORING
397 33707   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING
51  20351   KILLED  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING
199 1171    ACTIVE  WAITING Body Definition Lock    Null    None    XXX_MONITORING.DATA_CAPTURING
```

Comment: restarting the database will resolve the locks but until you post the script this will happen the next time you run the script

Comment: Thanks I restarted the machine(it was asking for a windows update anyway) and I can now run the script. Not sure if i can rely on it working when deployed on other machine/database.